# What do you call the previous version of a plane?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the previous version of a plane?
I am not sure if I am imagining things, but I feel like the word version isn't used at all to refer to previous versions of the planes.

I saw the word "**variant**" being used a lot, but I rarely see the word "version" and they rarely give the versions a name.
Is there a reason for it? What are the various ways to refer to the different "versions" of a plane?

Comment: Are you asking for something specific to *airplanes* or something generic to the previous version of *anything*? (I have no idea what a plane was called before it became something that could fly and was named an *airplane*.) Or do you mean the other sense of *plane*? (But the same question applies.)

Comment: an earlier model

Comment: Do these earlier model have version numbers like softwares do?

Comment: If you look at the conventions for [Boeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Commercial_Airplanes#Products), it might make things more clear. I am relatively sure similar terms are used across the airplane industry. I think "previous model" isn't used as much bc it implies that all of those previous models were replaced by the current model, which is not  the exact purpose of making a new airplane model.

Comment: I don't think there is one standard usage across the whole aviation world, the RAF used the term "Mark"' as in a Spitfire Mark I, Spitfire Mark II, Spitfire Mark III, Spitfire Mark IV,  Spitfire Mark V etc. So an earlier version would be an earlier mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there even is a common term in the aviation industry for the previous model of a plane it's not a standard part of the language that is recognized by everyone who speaks English. It's possible that different airplane manufacturers use different terminology and also that different situations require different terms. For instance, the 737 has been around for a long time and has been redesigned and configured for different uses. Yet many of these different 'versions' exist at the same time so you can't say that one is 'previous', and they're all 737's.

I think you're looking for something that doesn't exist, if you want a single word that describes all the possible scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

How about "predecessor"?

> a thing that has been followed or replaced by another. "the chapel was
>   built in 1864 on the site of its predecessor"